# Set Deliverynotification and Readnotification for outgoing Mails

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I send invoices and warnings/reminders to customers and now these mails should be flagged with a ***Deliverynotification*** and ***Readnotification***. So, I know when customers received and read the invoice.

```
MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
email.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
email.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess; // Deliverynotification? 
email.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(docDunPath));
email.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(docInvoicePath));
email.Subject = "-----------";
email.IsBodyHtml = true;                
email.Body = MailText;
```

Everything works so far, I just want to set the options for an automatic response when the recipient has read the mail. So, I can be sure he saw his invoice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after realising i used *System.Net.Mail* i switched to *Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices* and it works perfectly now.

```
EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);              
email.IsDeliveryReceiptRequested = true;                          
email.IsReadReceiptRequested = true;
```